# problems building the protobuf example apps

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm new to protobufs and was trying to learn more about using them. I've downloaded the protobuf packaged from [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list). There is a README.txt file inside the examples folder of the archive which gives instructions on how to build 2 example applications. However when I follow those instructions for building the java application:

```
make java
```

I get a lot of errors followed by:

> 100 errors
>   make: *** [javac_middleman] Error 1

All of the 100 errors seem to be classpath related, as this is a typical example:

> com/example/tutorial/AddressBookProtos.java:37: error: package com.google.protobuf does not exist

Any ideas about how to get passed this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that for some reason `protobuf` jar is not added to the classpath during compilation. To fix it you should open `examples/Makefile` and add  **`-cp protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar`** at the end of java complilation line `javac AddPerson.java ListPeople.java com/example/tutorial/AddressBookProtos.java`.

P.S. If you built you protobufs with maven the jar is located at `~/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.4.1/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar` (version of the jar might be different)

Comment: Thanks! Strange that they wouldn't make note of any of this in the README files... but you just solved a many hours long problem!

Comment: It's interesting & kind of frustrating that this works for my 2.4.1 installation on linux, but not for my 2.5.0rc1 installation on a mac...